# Format a text before displaying it in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, line-breaks, text-formatting

I have a text like:

```
Blablabla
Hello
How are you?
```

But it has to be stored in my database in the same text field like this:

```
Blablabla Hello How are you?
```

I am using Angular and I would like to know how to format the database text before displaying it inside the template like this.

```
<p>{{ value }}</p>
```

I know I should add a separator in the database but I don't know if it's possible to add a '\n' for example and then format the text before displaying it.

Comment: Make sure the line breaks are in the text in the first place, and use CSS to preserve them: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: How can I make sure the line breaks are in the text?

Comment: As with any user input sanitize it before sending to the view

Comment: So using ng-bind-html="trustedHtml" is not unsafe?

Comment: *How can I make sure the line breaks are in the text?* By editing the wrong text that is already in the database, and fixing the code that inserts text with line breaks but removes them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

In your controller

```
$scope.value = $scope.value.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.value);
```

in your view

```
<p ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></p>
```

OR

you can create a factory to use it everywhere

```
angular.module('app').filter('trustedHtml', function($sce) {
  return function(val) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
  };
});
```

In your controller

```
 $scope.value = $scope.value.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
```

in your view

```
 <p ng-bind-html="value | trustedHtml"></p>
```

SOLUTION:

```
 <p ng-bind-html="value"></p>
```

So Angular $sanitize deletes the tags that may be malicious like 'script'

Comment: The problem is that the text is being sent by users and I think it's not save to display it with ng-blind-html, they can add malicious scripts right?

Comment: Yes I think so but using ng-bind-html="trustedHtml" may be unsafe? I mean,  can the users inject scripts?

Comment: Okay I have used ng-bind-html="value" instead of trustAsHtml, so $sanitize filter the tags that may be unsafe like scripts